# Error when adapting batch size in tf.keras.utils.Sequence

Tags: keras, sequence, tensorflow2.0, data-generation

I study using tf.keras.utils.Sequence on Tensorflow 2.4.1. I used the example code in Sequence in API document (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) and finetuned by adding `on_epoch_end` function to adaptively change the `batch_size` value on every epoch.

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import random
import math

# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
# and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class CIFAR10Sequence(tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        print(self.batch_size)
        self.batch_size = int(random.randint(10, 100))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

However, in practice, the number of steps per epoch, which expected to change depending on the number of batches, remains unchanged. In fact, Tensorflow returns a WARNING, informing that they run out of data, and stop the training immediately. This problem happens when the initialize `batch_size` is smaller than the current `self.batch_size`.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches
```

Here is my guess, Tensorflow did adapt the batch size after every epoch, but somehow the model was still keeping the initial value. This problem never happened in Keras version 1. So far, I have no clue on solving this problem.
Edit 1: The number of training data is much larger than the number of batches.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly this problem. In my case, I update the data after every epoch (the number increases). I notice that the number of batches in each epoch  stays the same (although it should depend on the number of samples). My guess is that it is called once during initialization and not updated during each epoch.